# Swift 2 Using "contains" function with multidimensional array

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I am trying to do the simple task of finding if a (string) element exists in an array. The "contains" function works with a one-dimensional array, but not in a 2-dimensional array. 
Any suggestions? (Documentation on this function appears to be sparse, or I don't know where to look.)

Answer (score 3):

Updated for Swift 3

The `flatten` method has been renamed to `joined` now. So the usage would be

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].joined().contains(3) // true
```

---

For multi-dimensional array, you can use `flatten` to decrease one dimension. So for two-dimensional array:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].flatten().contains(7) // false

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].flatten().contains(3) // true
```

Answer (score 3):

The Swift standard library does not have "multi-dimensional arrays",
but if you refer to "nested arrays" (i.e. an array of arrays) then
a nested `contains()` would work, for example:

```
let array = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]
let c = array.contains { $0.contains("d") }
print(c) // true
```

Here the inner `contains()` method is

```
public func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
```

and the outer `contains()` method is the predicate-based

```
public func contains(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

which returns `true` as soon as the given element is found in one
of the inner arrays.

This approach can be generalized to deeper nesting levels.

Comment: Thanks! The Swift documentation does refer to multidimensional arrays but doesn't give much information on using them.

Answer (score 1):

Not as good as J.Wangs answer but another alternative - You can reduce the list to a single boolean value using the reduce(*,combine:*) function.

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]].reduce(false, combine: {$0 || $1.contains(4)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write an extension (Swift 3):

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Sequence {
    func contains2D(where predicate: (Self.Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool {
        return try contains(where: {
            try $0.contains(where: predicate)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let array = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]
var c = array.contains { $0.contains("d") }
print(c) // true

c = array.contains{$0[1] == "d"}
print(c)  //  true

c = array.contains{$0[0] == "c"}
print (c) //  true


if let indexOfC = array.firstIndex(where: {$0[1] == "d"}) {
    print(array[indexOfC][0]) // c
    print(array[indexOfC][1]) // d
} else  {
    print ("Sorry, letter is not in position [][letter]")
}

if let indexOfC = array.firstIndex(where: {$0[0] == "c"}) {
    print(array[indexOfC][1]) //  d
    print(array[indexOfC][0]) //  c
} else  {
    print ("Sorry, letter is not in position [letter][]")
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.